# python3 only one of the directory got imported in namespace package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming in python and trying to learn namespace packages.

I have namespace package `split_farm` in 2 directories path1 and path2 as below-

```
    $ tree .
    .
    ├── path1
    │   └── split_farm
    │       ├── common.py
    │       ├── cow.py
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── ox.py
    │       └── __pycache__
    │           └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    └── path2
        └── split_farm
            ├── chicken.py
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── __pycache__
            │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
            └── turkey.py

    6 directories, 9 files
```

Then I've extended path1 and path2 insto sys.path as below -

```
    $ python3
    Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import sys                
    >>> sys.path.extend(['path1', 'path2'])
    >>> import split_farm
    >>> split_farm.__path__
    ['path1/split_farm']
    >>> locals()
    {'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, 'split_farm': <module 'split_farm' from 'path1/split_farm/__init__.py'>, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None}
```

As seen above only 'path1/split_farm' got imported but not 'path2/split_farm'.

My code is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/python_beyond_the_basics/tree/org_large_progs_part3/ch01_namespace_packages).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is an easy way to do what you're doing.

Basically, Python imports modules by looking for them in each directory contained in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, in order. Once it finds a match, it stops there.

In this case, it finds `split_farm` in `path1`, imports it, and stops there. It would treat the `split_farm` in `path2` as a *totally different module*, which would be considered a namespace conflict.

It *is* possible with a whole bunch of custom import logic and screwing around with the loaded modules, but I wouldn't recommend it.

The much more idiomatic way would be to have both packages named different things in a parent package, or else to combine them into a single package.

Comment: interesting. I'm doing it as example program demonstrated in this course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/python-beyond-basics. chapter2 organizing_larger_programs/namespace_packages. I don't know how it worked for him. The only difference is he used 3.4 and mine is 3.5 which shouldn't be the cause I believe.